# OR statement in URL query string

Tags: http, rest, get, query-string

I need to support OR statement in REST API, and I don't know how to build right query string.
Maybe, something like this?

- /rest?author=Obama&author=McCain
- /rest?author=Obama|McCain

or maybe standard solution exists?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** You can have a string that represents all of the values. and in code, you'll break the string apart according to some delimiter.

`key=val1,val2,val3`

and lets say (in pseudo code): `var vals = explode( GETPARAMS['key'] , ',' )`

**Option 2:** You can use array notation in your url arguments:

`key[0]=val1&key[1]=val2&key[2]=val3`

and in code, the value of `key` will be an array: `array( val1, val2, val3 )`

Answer (score 0):

You could go for [OpenData filter](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/#45_Filter_System_Query_Option_filter) which allows complex filters.

Where the endpoint in your example would look like:

```
/rest?$filter=author eq Obama and author eq McCain

/rest?$filter=author eq Obame or author eq McCain
```

If you are using Asp.NET Web-Api you could use [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData).

Disclamer: Using OData in Web-Api works using Entity Framework (or something that uses IQueryable)

Comment: This looks like putting a sql-where-clause in the filter variable.